# Filter table data in function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've created a dashboard worksheet that performs some calculations on a table of data (AllDataModel). The calculations prevent me from using Pivot Tables.

I've applied a Slicer to my data table for date. While the table data appears to be updated, my calculated data isn't updating. How do I get my calculated fields to use the filtered table data?

Example calculation:

```
=SUMIF(AllDataModel!$B$2:$B$65536,CONCATENATE("*",C27,"*"), AllDataModel!$G$2:$G$65536)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution for this can easily be found with search keywords `excel sumif filtered range`. There are many sites and also videos available which will explain this.

In your case it should be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(INDEX(AllDataModel!$G$2:$G$65536,1),ROW($2:$65536)-ROW(AllDataModel!$G$2),0)))*(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(C27,AllDataModel!$B$2:$B$65536)))))
```